# multiple connection string same context

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need Help configuring an asp.net core 2.0 angular project with entity-framework 2.0, I need help to implement in the controller when user call an API like `ChangeDatabase(string databaseConexionString)`, then all the request made for that user will use the new connection string instead.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public AdminController(DatabaseContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult ChangeDatabase(string databaseConexionString)
    {            
         //change conexion string...
         return Ok("changed!");
    }


}
```

My startup.cs file, the configure services is the default

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I just want to change between databases and keep the same context class because the tables are the same, the only difference is the data.

Comment: Are you changing the connection string for only that request or is that changing the connection string going forward from that request?

Comment: @Nkosi i need to change the connection string for every request made for that user after that call, i will edit the question to avoid confusion, thanks